# Filled contour lines from a plot with color in R

Tags: r, colors, plot, fill, contour

I have the following code that will generate a plot with several contour lines. Now I would like to fill those contours or at least one (for example the 25% contour lines) with a specific color. I have try different options but I am not sure how to select the polygon area from a specific contour and filled it with a color.

```
dd1<-read.table(text="dist  depth
            4916.64 8.661827
            4916.64 14.789091
            4916.64 13.555909
            4916.64 12.92816
            4916.64 11.708774
            4916.64 15.28
            4916.64 13.369875
            4916.64 14.039655
            4916.64 13.454545
            4916.64 12.638261
            4916.64 13.251081
            4916.64 14.006341
            4916.64 12.64
            4916.64 15.521818
            4916.64 10.202121
            4916.64 14.816667
            4916.64 15.504
            9674.844    23.93
            11000.151   22.157143
            11414.31    22.72
            11414.31    25.7
            11414.31    19.07
            11414.31    23.085714
            9481.57 17.266667
            11414.31    26.8
            11414.31    19.382222
            5616.09 12.016667
            10658.02    18.873913
            11414.31    25.2
            11414.31    20.9
            11414.31    27.65
            11414.31    22.133333
            11414.31    30.9
            5616.09 23.3
            11172.718   20.391667
            9964.755    23.51
            5616.09 19.43
            5616.09 19.1
            4916.64 18.42
            8515.2  17.683333
            11414.31    22.128571
            11414.31    22.8608
            10391.095   24.955882
            10931.125   25.225
            6444.407    20.228571
            11276.257   23.77619
            10585.993   23.285714
            10641.214   20.653333
            9757.676    24.007143
            11414.31    18.817
            11414.31    23.525
            11414.31    22.873684
            11414.31    26.15
            10486.595   21.9
            11000.151   24.142857
            11414.31    24.3875
            10819.621   20.569231
            10360.088   29.345455
            9708.951    21.488235
            11414.31    30.775
            11414.31    25.5
            11414.31    18.477917
            10327.144   26.8625
            11414.31    26.12963
            11414.31    29.28125
            11414.31    23.166667
            10689.532   21.8625
            11414.31    28.328571
            11414.31    22.563158
            11414.31    25.490909
            11414.31    26.0625
            11414.31    34.5
            11414.31    17.375294",header=T)
```

Here is the code that will generate the plot. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
library(ks)
## auto bandwidth selection
H.pi2<-Hpi(dd1,binned=TRUE)*1
ddhat<-kde(dd1,H=H.pi2)

# Kernel contour plot
plot(ddhat,cont=c(95),drawpoints=TRUE,col="black",xlab="Distance (m)",lwd=2.5, 
        ylab="Depth (m)",ptcol="grey15",cex=0.7,
        xlim=c(min(dd1[,1]-dd1[,1]*0.4),max(dd1[,1]+dd1[,1]*0.4)),ylim=c(45,-1)) 

plot(ddhat,cont=c(25),add=TRUE,col="red",lwd=2.4)
plot(ddhat,cont=c(50),add=TRUE,col="seagreen2",lwd=2.4)
plot(ddhat,cont=c(75),add=TRUE,col="royalblue",lty=5,lwd=2.5)  

# End of the script
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `display="filled.contour2"` as an argument to `plot.kde`. For example :

```
plot(ddhat,cont=c(75),add=FALSE,lty=5,lwd=2.5, display="filled.contour2", col=c(NA,"blue"))
plot(ddhat,cont=c(95),drawpoints=TRUE,col="black",xlab="Distance (m)",lwd=2.5, 
      ylab="Depth (m)",ptcol="grey15",cex=0.7,
      xlim=c(min(dd1[,1]-dd1[,1]*0.4),max(dd1[,1]+dd1[,1]*0.4)),ylim=c(45,-1),add=TRUE) 
plot(ddhat,cont=c(50),add=TRUE,lwd=2.4, display="filled.contour2", col=c(NA,"green"))
plot(ddhat,cont=c(25),add=TRUE,lwd=2.4, display="filled.contour2",col=c(NA,"red"))
```

Which gives :

[image]

Comment: How can you specify/change the color from the filled.contour?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can use the `col` argument, but with a vector of two colours : one for the outside and one for the inside. For example : `plot(ddhat,cont=c(25),add=FALSE,lwd=2.4, display="filled.contour2",col=c("white","blue"))`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually just needed to change the color from the filled contour. For example from red to blue, but not the outside. In this example I imagine you would have to specify col=c(NA,"blue")?

Comment: Yes, you're right, you have to use `NA` for the first color, and take care of the order of your `plot` calls. I've updated my answer to take this into account.

Comment: One quick related question. I am trying to plot one contour kernel on top of the other, so I am trying to use different color options and transparency so that the end plot is easier to understand. However, for some reason when I exported the figure as a PDF the fill color (with transparency option) shows a grid pattern with the color (for example, plot(ddhat.day,cont=c(95),lwd=1,add=F,display="filled.contour2",col=c(0,"#8B000040")). I also tried using col=rgb to specify color and transparency but it shows the same. Any good suggestions on how to remove this grid pattern from the filling?