# Multiple Filled Contour plots on the

Tags: r, contour

I think my query is partially answered by this:

[Filled contour lines from a plot with color in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559055/filled-contour-lines-from-a-plot-with-color-in-r/15939795#15939795)

I have added a response to that post, but being quite old, I thought I might re-post it as a new question. If you can help me out, that would be great!

I have a matrix (G) that I need to separate into 3 zones on a plot, divided by two contours (cutoff1 and cutoff2).

```
depth = seq(mindepth,maxdepth,part)
width = seq(minwidth,maxwidth,part)
G = matrix(0,length(width),length(depth))

# G filled in with values at each coordinate from depth/width.

filled.contour2(width,depth,G,levels=seq(0,cutoff1),col=colors()[374])
filled.contour2(width,depth,G,levels=seq(cutoff1,cutoff2),col=colors()[411])
filled.contour2(width,depth,G,levels=seq(cutoff2,max(G)),col=colors()[50])
```

This doesn't work because consecutive filled.contour2 operations overwrite the previous ones. I can't post images because I'm new to posting on this site, but the three separated zones are simple and the separating contours do not overlap.

It looks like something along the lines of:

```
plot(width,depth,G,cont=c(cutoff1), display="filled.contour2", col=colors()[411])
```

should work, but obviously this isn't the right way to call plot.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to SO.  It would be helpful if you could elaborate on your variables, which packages you are using, etc.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thank you for your response. As it normally goes, after hours of struggling with this, 10 minutes after I posted the question I figured it out... My solution was to create a new color scheme and define the contours within filled.contour2: filled.contour2(width,depth,G,levels=c(0,cutoff1,cutoff2,max(G)),col=c(colors()[374],colors()[411],colors()[50]))

Comment: I'm not familiar with `filled.countour2`, however, you can try calling `par(new=TRUE)` in between each call to `filled.contour2` and see if that helps.  (yes the `new=TRUE` _is_ counterintuitive)

Comment: great!  well you can post what you discovered as a solution for others to find when they search

Comment: I meant to this question ;)